# Xamarin test cloud submit app and config file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

When submitting an app and test assembly to Xamarin Test Cloud using test-cloud.exe (version Xamarin.UITest.1.3.9.1500-dev) we also need to submit an App.config file (as our test assembly relies on configurable appSettings).

Initially I had hoped that everything within the bin directory (either Debug / Release depending on --assembly-dir provided) would be uploaded to Test Cloud.
This does not appear to be the case, my App.config file (XamarinMobileTests.dll.config) present in the bin directory is not uploaded.

So, to address this issue, I have attempted 2 potential solutions, none of which I have had any success with, these are as follows:

1. Using the --data parameter with the submit command (--data XamarinMobileTests\bin\Release\XamarinMobileTests.dll.config). This always seems to return an error: "**Data files must be located in the assembly directory or a sub folder.**"
   I have attempted to put this file in various locations, with no luck.
2. Specify appSetting values within the --test-params parameter. This executes the submit command without error and instantiates a test run in test cloud. However, the Xamarin.UiTest Sdk does not seem to have any support for accessing the --test-params specified. My only option seems to be using the Xamarin Web Api, figuring out the test run (also not available via the Sdk) and then fetching the test-params from the test run meta-data.

The documentation on their site is extremely limited for these parameters.

Has anyone experienced similar issues in the past or found a potential solution?

Ideally, the config file is uploaded by default. However, if this is not an option, then solution 1 would be my preferred choice.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the issue was with a trailing "\" on the --assembly-dir that was causing the config file specified in --data to not be uploaded.

Changing:

".\XamarinMobileTests\bin\Release\"

to:

".\XamarinMobileTests\bin\Release"

Resolved the issue and the config file was successfully uploaded.
It looks as if the test-cloud.exe does some flakey comparisons on file paths.